# WCF with AdventureWorks SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, wcf

I am testing the WCF facility with the AdventureWorks SQL Server database (The table name `Person`).

When testing it in the `wcftestclient.exe`, it gives red icon and says:

> This Operation is not supported in the WCF test client because it
>   uses type AdventureWorksDbWcf.Person

This is the service.svc.cs service class.

```
namespace AdventureWorksDbWcf
{   
    public class Service : IService
    {
        AW_DataClassesDataContext db = new AW_DataClassesDataContext();

        public Person GetOnePerson(int BusinessEntityID)
        {
            var _person = from one in db.Persons
                          select one;

            Person onlyOnly;

            return onlyOnly = _person.First<Person>();

        }

        public List<Person> ListOfPeople()
        {
            var _person = from one in db.Persons
                          select one;

            List<Person> list = _person.ToList();

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: this is the IService

[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Person GetOnePerson(int BusinessEntityID);

```
    [OperationContract]
    List<Person> ListOfPeople();

}
```

Have I missed something?

Please advise me.

thanks,

Comment: What does your class `AdventureWorksDbWcf.Person` look like??

Comment: This is the sample database provided by Microsoft. Name AdventureWorks200R2.

Comment: Sql server has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @darking050: I know which database it is - but **what does your C# class** for that table look like??? I assume you probably don't have the necessary WCF attributes on it - which is why the WCF Test Client can't call that service...... are you using Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework?? (or something else - and if so: **what** do you use??)

Comment: The WCF Test Client doesn't work with complex types. You'll have to write your own test harness.

Comment: The C# class for the table was auto generated. It is usual when you add the DB when creating the .dhtml file. and with the code above I am using Linq to SQL.

Comment: If the WCF Test Client doesn't work with complex types. So I need to make my own test envirmoent for testing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decorate the Person class with the appropriate [DataContract] attribute and the fields you'd like to expose with [DataMember].

If you are using the DataEntity or LinqToSQL, which auto-generate classes for the table, note that is best practice to create a "data" class to be used by the service instead of sending a class that is part of your business logic. Take a look at the [IDesign's WCF coding standards](http://idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20WCF%20Coding%20Standard.zip).

Comment: As I understand that, The Person Class was auto-generated when I added the SQL Database. And it is not advisable by Microsoft to edit that file. So, I will create another class "PersonSQL" marked with [dataMember] and connect it to the SQL Class. Then I will add it to the IService and implement it in the Service class. Please correct me if I missed something, I am still new to this.

Comment: You're on the right track. Note that is good practice to name DataContract classes with "Data" as suffix. In your case, it'd be PersonData. So a contract would be: PersonData GetPerson(...).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Person classes implementation but i think it should be good because it is a generated class if i'm not mistaken.

Does your interface have the right Service Contract and Operation Contracts?

[WCF tutorial](http://wcftutorial.net/Data-Contract.aspx)